# Insert HTML in docx file

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I have made an application that fills wordfiles with customxmlparts now I am trying to put text into a textfield, but it has HTML in it and I want it to show the styling of it. I tried converting it to rich text format but that just gets pasted in the word file. Here is an example of the code:

```
var taskId = Guid.NewGuid();
var tempFilePath = $"{Path.GetTempPath()}/{taskId}";

using (var templateStream = new FileStream($"{tempFilePath}.docx", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    templateStream.Write(template, 0, template.Length);
    // 1. Fill template.
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(templateStream, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainDocument = doc.MainDocumentPart;

        if (mainDocument.CustomXmlParts != null)
        {
            mainDocument.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(mainDocument.CustomXmlParts);
        }
        CustomXmlPart cxp = mainDocument.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
        foreach (var line in data.Lines)
        {
            if (line.MoreInfo != null && line.MoreInfo != " ") {

            }
        }
        var xmlData = ObjectToXml(data);

        using (var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(tempFilePath, xmlData))
        {
            cxp.FeedData(stream);
        }

        mainDocument.Document.Save();
    }               
}
```

Comment: or any way to put a enter in the doc file i tried  &#xD (just places it on the screen ) \u2029\n (makes a space) /n doesnt do anything

Answer (score 2):

You can't just write the HTML formatted text into a DOCX field, you would need to convert it into a WordprocessingML format.
However, there is another way that you could try and that is to insert an "AltChunk" element. That element represents a sort of like a placeholder which can reference a HTML file and then when the DOCX file is opened in MS Word, it will make that HTML to WordprocessingML conversion for you. For details see: [How to Use altChunk for Document Assembly](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/10/26/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly/)

Alternatively you could use some third party, like [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview), which can make that HTML to WordprocessingML conversion for you.
For example check this [Set Content example](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/set-content/402):

```
// Set content using HTML tags
document.Sections[0].Blocks[4].Content.LoadText(
    "Paragraph 5 <b>(part of this paragraph is bold)</b>", LoadOptions.HtmlDefault);
```